# How to get sum of transaction from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, for-in-loop

I'm trying to return the sum of all transactions but the program isn't returning the sum

**question**

Define a function, totalTransactions, that takes an array of objects called transactions.

totalTransactions should return the total amount spent on all transactions.

**my code**

```
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
  let sum = 0

  for (key in transactions) {
    transactions[key] += sum;
  }

  return sum;
}
```

**Given information**
This is a nested data structure. Similar to 2D arrays, we can use a combination of bracket and dot notation to access nested key-values pairs

For example, to access the first name and amount values, we could use the index of 0 (for the first list item) followed by the individual key values:

**Given example code**

```
let transactions = [
  {
    name: "Tons of glitter",
    amount: 70
  },
  {
    name: "Porcelain Pink Flamingos",
    amount: 92
  },
  {
    name: "Chandelier replacement",
    amount: 10000,
  },
  {
    name: "Dinner at TGIF x6",
    amount: 350
  }
];

lastFridayNight(transactions) // => 10512
```

Comment: can you provide example data? what does the data structure look like? what is "each" transaction expected to look like?

Comment: most likely, `reduce()` is what you're looking for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: @ThisGuy Just updated the question with the example data

Comment: @user19964609 on the MDN link I posted above, there is an example which is almost exactly what you need. `Sum of values in an object array`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#sum_of_values_in_an_object_array

Comment: Hi, Mist, it seems like your question has been answered. Could you mark an answer as the one which worked for you? The reputation is very helpful for those who've answered

Answer (score 3):

Since you are computing an aggregate, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is your friend here.

Start with a `sum` equal to the number 0. At each intermediate step, add the `amount` of the current transaction to the aggregate.

```js
let transactions = [
  {
    name: "Tons of glitter",
    amount: 70
  },
  {
    name: "Porcelain Pink Flamingos",
    amount: 92
  },
  {
    name: "Chandelier replacement",
    amount: 10000,
  },
  {
    name: "Dinner at TGIF x6",
    amount: 350
  }
];

function totalTransactions(transactions) {
  return transactions.reduce((sum, tx) => sum + tx.amount, 0);
}

console.log(totalTransactions(transactions));
```

**EDIT**

I like the way the above snippet works and would probably go that route if it was my project. However, if the goal here is to fix your code in the simplest way possible, here is an alternative solution.

```
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
  let sum = 0

  for (const tx of transactions) {
    sum += tx.amount;
  }

  return sum;
}
```

There are 2 main changes here:

1. Changing your loop from `for .. in` to `for .. of` iterates over the transactions, not the keys in the array.
2. This line `transactions[key] += sum;` does not make much sense. You are adding the value of `sum` (always `0` in this case) to an object. My test shows it coercing both values to a string a concatenating them. This is definitely not what you want! Instead, you want to get the value `amount` from each transaction and add it to `sum`.

Comment: This is a very modern implementation using excellent, state of the art notation. This is the ideal implementation, IMHO

Comment: Although a good solution, it's probably above the skill of OP at the moment. OP is struggling with fairly basic looping and `+=`, so it's probably not the best moment to introduce `reduce`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r So what do you recommend to use

Comment: @Mist - I added another way to solve this that leaves most of your code as-is. Also worth noting, the `forEach` solution is pretty straightforward as well.

Answer (score 1):

To help understand, your data is an array of Objects. So, we can use index notation to iterate through each Object, but then we use dot notation to access the value of a property of that object.

"forEach" is a function of Array object, it is a nice shorthand over "for( let i =0, i++, i < t.length ){ t[i] do code here}"

You can access properties of Objects in a few ways:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/access-object-properties-javascript/

So, we are iterating through each "item" of the transaction list and accessing the 'amount' property, adding it to a function scoped ( via let ) variable "sum" and then returning that value.

```js
function totalTransactions(t) {
  let sum = 0;
  t.forEach(item => {
    sum += item.amount;
  })
  return sum;
}
```

Another way to access the property, similar notation to arrays:

```js
function totalTransactions(t) {
  let sum = 0;
  t.forEach(item => {
    sum += item['amount'];
  })
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Great comment, @3limin4t0r . Yes, I was actually just diving into that. Hopefully my explanation will help shed some light on what this function is doing. :D

Answer (score 0):

You're using `for..in` on the array, try `for..of`. May I see an example array that would be used an the totalTransactions parameter? Also, I'm sure you should switch around the reassignment like this `sum += transactions[key];` so that sum is reasigned and not the object.

Comment: Just updated the question with the example data given